# .then(function) doesn't run function

Tags: javascript, userscripts

I have this userscript for GreaseMonkey. I created a function (A) which calls an other function (B). I want to wait running the A function further and wait for the B function to return. Function B contains a button, so in fact I want A to wait for the button press.

I tried this with the `async` and `await` but that didn't work for me show I now tried to use the `.then()` option. In the `then()` I created a function (`nextI`) to increase the `i` after running function B.

```
function A(){
    var i = 0
    while (i < 3){
        var data = jsonResponse[i];
        var x = data.x;
        var y = data.y;
        B(x, y).then(
            nextI(i)
        )
    }
)

function B(x, y){
    // do some stuff
    let button = document.getElementById("button");
    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
        console.log("Button clicked.");
        return
   });
}

function nextI(i){
    return i + 1
}
```

So I want to pause A until script B is done and I clicked the button.

Comment: `B()` does not return a promise.  It actually doesn't return anything

Comment: You cannot return to your function from within a callback.

Comment: If `B()` returns the increased `i`, would that solve the problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323   I think you need a promise

Comment: Which is it? Do you want to wait for `B` to return or for the button to be pressed? Those are very different things.

Comment: @George You can return a `Promise` from `B` and resolve it from within your event listener callback.

Comment: `while (i < 3)` creates infinity loop, because `i` is never increased

Comment: Doesn't make sense to make B return a Promise though.

Answer (score 1):

## 1. `Number` is passed by value

Thus, giving `i` to `nextI` increases a local copy (i.e. the input parameter).

## 2. `B` doesn't return `Promise`

```
function B(x, y) {
  let button = document.getElementById("button");

  // FIX HERE
  return new Promise(resolve =>
    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
      console.log("Button clicked.");
      resolve('some data')
    })
  )
}
```

## 3. `Promise#then` accepts a function

So, `B (nextI (i))` isn't correct, but `B(() => nextI (i))`.

## *N*. Other issues

There should be other issues there. For example, you're running functions whose return type/value is `Promise` in a *fire&forget* way. Take a look at [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) or [`Promise.race`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race).

Answer (score 0):

before using `.then()`, you first have to return a promise.

```
function B(x, y){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
     // do something here

     let button = document.getElementById("button"); 
     button.addEventListener("click", () => { 
          console.log("Button clicked."); 
          resolve('foo');
     });

  });
}
```

take a look https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: They want to return data from within the `click` callback and it might be necessary to explain how to do that.

Comment: they can use in the promise ---  `let button = document.getElementById("button");
    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
        console.log("Button clicked.");
        resolve('foo');
   });`

Comment: we are resolving promise when the button is clicked, so `.then()` will be executed after the button is clicked.